# How to setup a webpack dev server using both historyApiFallback and proxying remote api requests?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a react application which uses `react-router`, so it's making use of HTML5 history API, I've tried `historyApiFallback` set to `true` to serve 404 paths serving the same `index.html` instead of returning the HTTP response.

That single page application does some requests to a *remote* API server, that's why I also need to proxy some requests to the express server I'm also running while developing. Web react application is served on port 3000 and API runs on port 3001.

So I've tried:

```
devServer:{
    contentBase: 'src/www',  //Relative directory for base of server
    devtool: 'eval',
    hot: true,        //Live-reload
    inline: true,
    port: 3000,        //Port Number
    host: 'localhost', //Change to '0.0.0.0' for external facing server
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      '^\/users|sitters|bookings': {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001',
        rewrite: function(req) {
          req.url = req.url.replace(/^\/api/, '');
        }
      }
    }
  },
  devtool: 'eval',
  output: {
    path: buildPath,    //Path of output file
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
```

So I what I want is hitting the remote api server if the request's path starts with either `/users` or `/sitters` or `/bookings` but go for `historyApiFallback` (serve `index.html`) otherwise.

Of course right now historyApiFallback works always serving the HTML file but I'd also need the proxy to be working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Disclaimer. This answer might be outdated

### In Express middleware stack order matters.

Proxy should be set up at webpack config first than `historyApiFallback`, this is how it should look like:

```
  devServer:{
    contentBase: 'src/www',  //Relative directory for base of server
    devtool: 'eval',
    hot: true,        //Live-reload
    inline: true,
    port: 3000,        //Port Number
    host: 'localhost', //Change to '0.0.0.0' for external facing server
    proxy: {
      '^\/users|sitters|bookings': {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001',
        rewrite: function(req) {
          req.url = req.url.replace(/^\/api/, '');
        }
      }
    },
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
```

So of course proxy can be changed to any pattern or regex as an application needs it. In my case that's what I needed.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Using webpack 5.37.1 it seems like proxy is loaded first regardless of the ordering of the devServer options.

Comment: @Jitsusama yeah. My question is way too old. It was 2016 back then

Answer (score 2):

I end up with following solution:

```
const REMOTE_URL = process.env.REMOTE_URL || 'http://localhost:8090/';

const config = {
    output: {
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './app',
        proxy: [{
            context: '/api',
            target: REMOTE_URL,
            pathRewrite: {
                '^/api' : '/'
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

So all request to `http://locahost:port/api/` goes through proxy, and `/api` rewrited.

For example `http.get('/api/users')` go to just `/users`.

Btw. Object inside proxy is just [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) [configuration](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-middleware-options).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using webpack v4 and adding proper value for `pathRewrite` inside `proxy` worked for me.

For example, you are hosting client on `localhost:8080` and API on `localhost:3000`. Then your webpack `devServer` section will go like below.

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
        '/graphql': {
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
            target: 'http://localhost:3000/api'
        }
    }
}
```