# refresh throwing 404 error after implementing routing - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have implemented the Routing in my React APP. Refresh was not working on my local machine then I Followed the below URL to fix that:

[React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

I used below code:

```
 devServer: {
historyApiFallback: true,
contentBase: './',
hot: true
},
```

this code fix the things on my local machine, but when I moved my changes over the server(staging) it again start throwing me error. Then I tried number of things in devServer, but I am not able to find the exact that could solve my issues, I am new bee in ReactJs that's why I am facing this. I have tried below code as well:

```
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 80,
    hot: true,        //Live-reload
    inline: true,
    //port: 3000,        //Port Number
    host: 'http://reachjsapp.com/', //Change to '0.0.0.0' for external facing server
    proxy: {
        '^\/fetchUser|editStaff': {
            target: 'http://reachjsapp.com/',
            rewrite: function (req) {
                req.url = req.url.replace(/^\/api/, '');
            }
        }
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    // hot: true,
}
```

and [this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138936/how-to-setup-a-webpack-dev-server-using-both-historyapifallback-and-proxying-rem)

But no luck, Please help me.

Comment: What is the error or what are you seeing?

Comment: did you remember to put the same config for `stagingServer`? Maybe you're only doing this for devServer, and never updating staging

Comment: @towc, can you please post answer with these settings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it.. yeahhhhh

I have added the following lines in web.config file, and it works:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Happy Coding.. :)